# Create destination on SAP Gateway hub system

Tags: sapui5

I've developed a SAPUI5 using the SAP WebIDE at SCP. This app uses an external REST API which I've registered on "Destinations" on SCP and it's working fine. The problem is when I deployed to our SAP Gateway hub system (on-premise). The app are trying to call the URL of REST API locally.

Is there any way to register a destination on SAP Gateway like I did on SCP? I've tried a RFC connection but didn't works.

Comment: You need to use the SAP router, [here the documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi71/7.1/en-US/48/6b41efb74c07bee10000000a42189d/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Comment: You can store the base URL in a config file and then prefix your path with that - just ensure that, where used, the based URL is accessible from the User's point of access.

Comment: did the external API need a destination? External services often do not have CORS enabled so you can call them straight up.